# Circular orbit word problem

Tags: calculus

How would I solve the following problem?

A particle is moving on the circular orbit $x^2+y^2=41$. As it passes through the point $(5,4)$ its y coordinate is decreasing at the rate of $2$ units per second. At what rate is the x coordinate changing?

I know the distance formula is $x^2+y^2=1$

so I did $\frac{d}{dt}=2x\frac{dx}{dt}+2y\frac{dy}{dt}$

which is $x\frac{dx}{dt}+y\frac{dy}{dt}=0$

$x\frac{dx}{dt}=-y\frac{dy}{dt}$

$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{-y}{x}(-2)$

$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{-4}{5}(-2)$
but would this correct.

Comment: Yeah! You have done it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was done correctly, except for the worrying reference to the "distance formula" $x^2+y^2=1$.

We are **given** that $x^2+y^2=41$. We are also given some information about $\frac{dy}{dt}$, and are asked about $\frac{dx}{dt}$.  This is a  *related rates* problem, easier than most. We are given a rate (rate of change, derivative), and are as ked about another derivative, the derivative of a related quantity. Normally, we solve such a problem by **finding** a formula that captures the relationship between the quantities. Then we differentiate. But in this case the relationship is given to us explicitly.

Start from $x^2+y^2=41$. Differentiate both sides with respect to $t$. We get
$$2x\frac{dx}{dt}+2y\frac{dy}{dt}=0,$$
which looks somewhat better as 
$$x\frac{dx}{dt}+y\frac{dy}{dt}=0.\tag{$1$}$$
Now **freeze** the situation at the instant when $x=5$ and $y=4$. At that instant, we have $\frac{dy}{dt}=-2$. So at that instant
$$5\frac{dx}{dt}+(4)(-2)=0,$$
which says that at that instant $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\dfrac{8}{5}$.

We substituted particular values and then solved. But your style (solve and then substitute) works just as well. From $(1)$ we get
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{y}{x}\frac{dy}{dt}.$$
Set $x=5$, $y=4$, and $\frac{dy}{dt}=-2$.

Comment: thanks for the help yes I understand the problem better now.